# Ternary Operator in JSP EL fails

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Is nesting of EL Expressions in Ternary Operator allowed?

What is wrong with the following expression?

```
<input class="text_field" type="text" name="receivedBy" id="receivedBy" style="width:250px;"  maxlength="64" value="${empty obj.val ? obj1.attr1.val ' ' obj2.attr1.val: obj3.val"}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually not nesting EL expressions (nesting would look like `${foo${bar}baz}` which is actually not possible). You are attempting to concat EL outcomes as a String. You cannot concat Strings in EL that way. Your best bet is to use `c:set` to preset it.

```
<c:set var="obj1obj2val" value="${obj1.attr1.val} ${obj2.attr1.val}" />
<input value="${empty obj.val ? obj1obj2val : obj3.val}" />
```

Comment: This is the approach I took finally. Apparently, the obj1 did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

just try with the below one

```
<input class="text_field" type="text" name="receivedBy" id="receivedBy" style="width:250px;"  maxlength="64" value="${empty obj.val ? obj1.attr1.val ' ' obj2.attr1.val: obj3.val } "/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the brace is closed in code. Issue is not about the brace.

Comment: @icarus what is the single empty quotes between obj1.attr1.val and obj2.attr1.val

Comment: That was supposed to be a white space. But removing that also still maintains the problem.